# show a div and go to the anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

**Hello**

Is there any way to let this code work!
I am trying to show the DIV (slidingDiv) and go to the selected ANCHOR (#anchor-01 + #anchor-02 + #anchor-03)...
This code let me only go to the first line in the DIV.
So please, how can jump/scrool to the exact anchor?
THanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test show hide tab</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .slidingDiv {
        background-color: #99CCFF;
        padding:20px;
        margin-top:10px;
        border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
        }
        .show_hide {
        display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#anchor-01" class="show_hide">Show/hide 01</a> -- <a href="#anchor-02" class="show_hide">Show/hide 02 </a> -- <a href="#anchor-03" class="show_hide">Show/hide 03</a>
<hr>

<div class="slidingDiv">

    <div id="anchor-01">
        <h2>Tite for link anchor  01</h2>
        Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>

    <div id="anchor-02">
        <h2>Tite for link anchor  02</h2>
        Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>

    <div id="anchor-03">
        <h2>Tite for link anchor  03</h2>
        Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you're saying you want the three contents visible at any time, just scroll the parent? Huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

https://jsfiddle.net/6zg19ap0/

You need to pass e into the function then you can check the id of the clicked link, then just scroll to the div that has the class "div+id":

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(e){

    var id = e.currentTarget.id;

    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div"+id).offset().top},
    'slow');

});
```

Comment: i like a lot your code and idea, thanks a lot for your quick anser.

Comment: This fiddle demo seems is not working. It shows and hides all divs at the same time. (tested in Chrome)

Comment: That is what it is meant to do, it should show all and then animate scroll to the selected div.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var $divs = $(".slidingDiv").children();
  
  $divs.hide(); /* HIDE CHILDREN INSTEAD */
  
  $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    var id = this.hash;
    $divs.not(id).stop().slideUp();
    $(id).slideToggle();
  });

});
```

```css
html, body{height:100%; margin:0; font:16px/20px sans-serif;}

/* ALL YOU NEED to get started */
.slidingDiv       { background-color: #99CCFF; }
.slidingDiv > div { padding:20px; }
```

```html
<!-- Add #anchor-NN to the HREF of the children elements buttons too!!! -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#anchor-01" class="show_hide">Show/hide 01</a> --
<a href="#anchor-02" class="show_hide">Show/hide 02 </a> --
<a href="#anchor-03" class="show_hide">Show/hide 03</a> <hr>

<div class="slidingDiv">

  <div id="anchor-01">
    <h2>1 Tite for link anchor  01</h2>
    1 Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#anchor-01" class="show_hide">hide</a>
    <br><br><br>
  </div>

  <div id="anchor-02">
    <h2>2 Tite for link anchor  02</h2>
    2 Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#anchor-02" class="show_hide">hide</a>
    <br><br><br>
  </div>

  <div id="anchor-03">
    <h2>3 Tite for link anchor  03</h2>
    3 Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#anchor-03" class="show_hide">hide</a>
    <br><br><br>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the code work perfectly, but it show only the targeted div, and me, i want the visitors to see others div by scrolling by mouse...but your idea i will use it in other project.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use `<a name="anchor-01">` on the receiving end of the in-page link; div IDs aren't treated as link targets.  In this case, however, since your targets are hidden when the link is clicked, that wouldn't give the results you want.

This explicitly scrolls the page to the div with ID matching the link href:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".slidingDiv").hide();
      $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

        var target = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 300);
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
.slidingDiv {
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #3399FF;
}
.show_hide {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#anchor-01" class="show_hide">Show/hide 01</a> -- <a href="#anchor-02" class="show_hide">Show/hide 02 </a> -- <a href="#anchor-03" class="show_hide">Show/hide 03</a>
<hr>

<div class="slidingDiv">

  <div id="anchor-01">
    <h2>Tite for link anchor  01</h2>
    Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>

  <div id="anchor-02">
    <h2>Tite for link anchor  02</h2>
    Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>

  <div id="anchor-03">
    <h2>Tite for link anchor  03</h2>
    Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @daniel-beck, your code work as i need it.
Thanks again